# Vagrant update VBox Guest Addition after system upgrade

Tags: linux, bash, linux-kernel, vagrant, virtualbox

I found this interesting plugin [vagrant-vbguest](https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest) for the automatically update the Guest Addition CD, it check the guest addition installed version, compare with the current VirtualBox version and update it, but when in the provision runs `sudo apt-get upgrade` the kernel is upgraded and the Guest Addition needs to be rebuild for the new kernel.
Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Comment: As I understand from project's readme, this plugin finds and installs VBox Guest Additions package, corresponded to the current kernel package. It *doesn't build guest additions from sources*. Am I right?

Comment: I When the VM starts the Guest Addition of the VBox Host is compared with the installed on the box iff differs the install the Host Guest Addition, but if you update the kernel version the Guest Addition needs to rebuild the kernel modules for the new kernel version and this plugin didn't  do this